# reload popup page by using spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, reload

I am using a controller to get the form values from the html. And doing some kind of validations. If validation fails i want to reload that popup by throwing the validation message and the popup page view name to reload the popup page. Like

1. If i have a page A, in that page A there is a button B.
2. Now if i click the button B, there will be open a popup window C.
3. Here in the page C, if i click the form submit. It will goes to the controller.
4. Here in the controller i do some validations, if validation fails i just want to reload that popup page C with the error message.

Any body can help to overcome the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to do [here](http://www.html-form-guide.com/files/contact-form/popup-captcha-form-1/a-page.php) It can be achieved by basic JQuery, CSS, js. Explorer some. if you have to validate it from data base and than show use `<f:ajax />` this is whole work do some effort

Comment: What server tools and technology are you going to use? and what is the client's environment ?

Comment: html and java. In html we are using jquery and java script. And project is google app engine type.

Comment: java? spring? you can consider using primefaces like this: http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/dialog.html

Comment: JQuery will more preferable like Patil's link

Answer (score 3):

It will be easy if you use jQuery UI Modal.
Just go through [this link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)